# Posting data with HttpClient on Nginx.. Error 411 C#

Tags: c#, post, nginx, httpclient

I'm testing the new Framework .Net 4.5 introducing new classes like HttpClient.
I'm trying to login into a vbulletin forum and posting a subject.

It works perfectly using WampServer, but when I try with Nginx i've a 411 Error, Content-Lenght Required.

This is my code :

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

/* login part skipped, it works */

postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("do", "postthread"));
postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("f", "8"));
postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("loggedinuser", "1"));
postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("message", "myMessage"));
postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("subject", "mySubject : " + new Random().Next()));
postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("securitytoken", secure_id));
postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("vbseo_is_retrtitle", "1"));
postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("vbseo_retrtitle", "1"));
postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("posthash", posthash));
postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("poststarttime", poststarttime));

HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
HttpRequestMessage msg3 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost/newthread.php?do=postthread&f=8");

// Adding all headers from the resp2, containing cookie value to stay connected
// I think, here is the problem, when passing the 'Transfer-Encoding' and 'Transfer-EncodingChunked' values
foreach (var header in resp2.Headers)
   msg3.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);

msg3.Content = content;
var resp3 = client.SendAsync(msg3).Result;
resp3.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string html = resp3.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

When I see the msg3.Content.Headers.ContentLength, I've a value.. So I don't understand why Nginx throw me this error :/

After Googling, i saw that http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpChunkinModule but I don't want to modify the server..

Thanks for any help..

Comment: Might be an idea to run your requests through Fiddler. It might be a little more revealing.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem, but in my case I upgraded Nginx to 1.4.x.

There are various reasons for error 411 with nginx ([fix-nginx-411-length-required-error](http://www.lamnk.com/blog/computer/fix-nginx-411-length-required-error/))

- client sent invalid “Content-Length” header
- client sent … method without “Content-Length” header
- **client sent “Transfer-Encoding: chunked” header**

before nginx 1.3.9, “Transfer-Encoding: chunked” is not supported